# Simple Gridview with Drag and drop Reorder

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a simple `Gridview` as so

```
<asp:GridView ID="taskGrid" Width="100%" OnSelectedIndexChanged="taskGrid_SelectedIndexChanged"
 AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        Choose Items from Drop Down Lists
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="5%" ItemStyle-Width="5%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TaskID") %>' 
                                Width="10px" Height="10px" ID="imgRedX" ToolTip='<%# Eval("TaskID") %>' 
                                ImageUrl="~/Images/redX.png"  OnClick="taskGrid_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                                runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="47.5%" ItemStyle-Width="47.5%"
                        DataField="ServerName" HeaderText="Deploy Dashboard" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="47.5%" ItemStyle-Width="47.5%"
                        DataField="ApplicationName" HeaderText="Deploy Task" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

What I want to be able to do it incorporate basic drag and drop reordering of rows.

I have looked at a lot of solutions and even thought of a *Reorder List*, but nothing really fits my simple needs. This `Gridview` is powered by code behind where I populate a custom object (no `Datasource Controls`).

I am interested in *AJAX*, but only if it updates the object as well, not just the `Grid Container`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement it havingthis things into account:

1. you need to keep the order on the server side, so that a full postback will show you the correct order
2. you need something ([perhaps a jQuery plugin?](http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/)) which allows you to visually swap the rows
3. you need to modify the script in a way that can find the keys of the source and destination rows on client side (you, could, i.e. include them in a hidden filed inside a template in your gridview, and assign its value on RoWDataBound)
4. you need to [create a web service or static page method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998.aspx) to send the changes from the client to the server
5. tou need to [send the changes from the client to the web service or static page method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515101%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
6. you also need to [handle ajax errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398934.aspx) (go to the client script part of this post):

So, no, there's no easy way to do it. Unless C1 or Telerik have some paid controlthat does it.